# How to take snap shot of a <form> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

There are multiple `<input />` and `<textarea>` in the `<form>`,but **none have their id or name.**

Is it possible to take a snap shot of every thing inside the `<form>` and render it when need?

Comment: What do you mean by "render it when needed"?

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form, or do you just want to save the entire structure for later?

Comment: @zombat,you are right.And the order of elements may be different when it's shown

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would have a bunch of inputs lacking names and id's, but you could cycle through and generate a name/id for each, and then serialize them using $.serialize();

```
// Give all a name (e0, e1, e2...)
$(":input").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr("name", "e"+i);
});

// Serialize the data
var data = $("#formid").serialize(); // ex: e0=zip&e1=foo&e2=bar
```

Comment: In order to work properly serialize requires that form fields have a name attribute.

Comment: You have to have some way to identify each field. What good are they if they aren't differentiated?

Comment: It's hard to identify,the order of elements may be different when it's shown

Comment: So the order is random, and the fields are anonymous. I'm sorry, but I simply don't see any good in that at all. Can you tell us what it is you're doing?

Comment: If the order is fixed,how to render it efficiently using the serialized data?

Comment: @unknown, I'm not sure what you mean. If you tell us what you are doing we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

```
var formdata = $("#formid").serialize();
```

Comment: In order to work properly serialize requires that form fields have a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** This answer works for checkboxes, radio buttons, input and textareas. If you wanted select support, just add an additional test/type and parallel setter.

Store the values:

```
var values = $.map($("form :input"), function(n, i){ 
    if(n.is(':checkbox, :radio'))
      return [n.is(':checked'), "check"];
    else
      return [n.val() , "val"];
};
```

Restore the values:

```
$("form :input").each(function(i, el){
   var val = values[i];
   if(val[1] == "check"){
       if(val[0] == true) $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
       else $(this).removeAttr('checked');
   } else {
       $(this).val(val[1]);
   }
});
```

**This assumes the same order both times.** It is (dare I say) *impossible* to store values without `keys` and then restore them in a different order, and still have the values match up to the correct fields. You need `name` or `id` to differentiate.. period.

Comment: @Jonathan Well yours has more merit to actually function... a keyless orderless list is well, quite frightening :) Hey... are you hiding from me on GTalk? :D

Comment: For radio and checkbox,what I care is whether it's checked or not.Not its value.

Comment: What difference does it make if it's clicked if it has no value, sort-order, or identification!?

Comment: @unknown I updated my answer to give you an idea how to use it for other elements.